# Ajax pop up window

Tags: php, css, ajax, popupwindow

I would like to create an Ajax pop up window that will show when a user clicks a link or image. I would like to pass any values desired from the popup window to the parent window, or to any other page ( if a link within popup window navigates to a new page). Also, how do I decide if a link will load within the popup window or parent window? I will use php pages for this. What code will I use to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

you could use jQueryUI http://www.jqueryui.com

Answer (score 0):

You could use one of the many lightboxes that can be found online, some good ones include [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/), [shadowbox](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/) and [Lightbox evolution](http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-lightbox-evolution/115655)

As for loading within the popup or the parent window, you can just use target="_parent" and target="_self" for this.